# Looking for a <Marquee> alternative that is supported in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, marquee

I am trying to find a very neat, very stable alternative to the `<marquee>` element that supports both CSS and AngularJS.  So far, I have incorporated jQuery-WebTicker (found [here](https://github.com/jonmifsud/Web-Ticker/)) which does work quite nicely but has a few flaws which is making my website look a little unprofessional (no disrespect, but I'm not sure if they're still providing support).

I also came across an Angular example (found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thenetfreaker/qt0rmahr/2/)) but to be honest it's a little complicated for my new javascript skills so far.  I need it to scroll left to right mainly and be configurable.

I am using a service to pull in an RSS feed from a News site and display all headlines in a continuous loop.  I also need to be able to update the marquee with new content every 5 minutes or so.  And it would be preferable if I could update the marquee at the end of the loop, so the content doesn't jump whilst someone is reading it.

Does anyone know of a good alternative, or could assist me in creating my own (maybe streamlined from the Angular demonstration mentioned above)?

I have looked at a 'lot' of jQuery demos but nothing seems to work 100%.  Most of them don't seem to maintain consistency when scrolling large arrays of text.

Comment: _“[…] which is making my website look a little unprofessional”_ – isn’t that what marquee-like effects do in general …?

Comment: Yes, maybe correct  :)  However, I am trying to create a running news feed across the bottom of a visual signboard.  Normally a marquee would look tacky, but in this case, it does add a good look to the site.  It just doesn't look good when the news feed keeps displaying the same headline over or showing inconsistent gaps in-between news items.